# how detect button pressed event of local notification?

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

Hello I am using local notification in my application. When local notification generate then it will look like this image !

[local notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Art/local_notification.jpg)
Now how detect that user pressed close button or view details buttons? Have any way to detect or handle event on these buttons?

Thanks in advances...

Comment: check this tutorial http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/

Comment: may be this method will call - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

Comment: @Pravi that will detect when user click on view details button not when click on close button. And thanks for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for view button i think you already know that you can detecet it by `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` ,, but for the close button no way right now to handle it .. also if the screen is locked there is will be no buttons it just will call "view app" in case you unlocked the device.